# Center View vertically in relation to the Views next to it

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, interface-builder

Given the layout below:

[image: Base layout]

I wanted to know if it's possible to center vertically the `ImageView` on the left in relation to the views on the right so that, if any of the labels grow, the `ImageView` would still be on the center (left image) and not on top (right image).

[image: desired layout]
[image: wrong layout]

I tried constraining the `ImageView`'s top to the upper label and its bottom to the lower label but I haven't been able to se in a way that autolayout would try to "satisfy both". Trying to change any priority or changing the constraint to a inequality only makes the `ImageView` goes up or down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you really mean **Vertically** not **Horizontally**?

Embed your two labels into a Vertical stack view, and constrain the image view centered to the stack view.

Alternatively, for even fewer constraints needed...

- Embed your two labels into a Vertical stack view
- Embed the image view and that "labels stack view" into a Horizontal stack view
- set the Alignment of the Horizontal stack view to Center

[image]